# How to properly map a child - @Manytoone-> Parent relation where parent has an @EmbeddedID in JPA with Hiberate

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to have a bi-directional relationship between the child(ZonePoint_DTO) and parent(ZoneDTO), where the parent has a composite key.

The current mapping is resulting in nulls being entered in the child(ZonePoint_DTO) table when I try to enter a whole parent object(ZoneDTO) with a list of child(ZonePoint_DTO) entities. Please note the I have set cascade type to Cascade.PERSIST.

I am using JpaRepository.save() to save Parent(ZoneDTO)

Below are the entity classes.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ZoneDTO implements GenericPJM<ZoneDTO_Id>, Persistable<ZoneDTO_Id> {

  private static Set<String> zoneNamesList;
  @EmbeddedId private ZoneDTO_Id id;

  private Integer noOfPolygons;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "zoneDTO", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST)
  private List<ZonePointDTO> zonePointsList;

  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    boolean result = !zoneNamesList.contains(id.getZoneName());
    System.out.println(
            "__________________________isNew() called for " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "result= " + result);
    return result;
  }

  public static void setZoneNamesList(Set<String> zoneNamesListNew) {
    zoneNamesList = zoneNamesListNew;
  }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class ZoneDTO_Id implements GenericPJM_Id {
    String zoneName;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ZonePointDTO implements GenericPJM<Long> {

  @JsonIgnore @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
  private double xValue;
  private double yValue;
  private Integer polygonNumber;
  @ManyToOne private ZoneDTO zoneDTO;
}
```

The JSON format I am sending:

```
{       
        "type":"ZoneDTO",
        "id": {"zoneName":"SAMPLE"},
        "noOfPolygons": 1,
        "zonePointsList": [
            {
                "type":"ZonePointDTO",
                "xValue": 10,
                "yValue": 39.5,
                "polygonNumber": 1
            },
            {
                "type":"ZonePointDTO",
                "xValue": 10,
                "yValue": 39,
                "polygonNumber": 1
            }
         ]
}
```

I want to cascade persist the parent object(ZoneDTO), all at once and hopefully minimal DB calls.
Currently, data is getting persisted, both parent and child. But the child mapping column is saving nulls.

Any comments or workarounds or other methods will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's simple: you're persisting ZonePoint_DTO objects (Side note: a DTO is a Data Transfer Object. Why do you name your entities DTO? They're not data transfer objects). ZonePoint_DTO has a persistent property named zoneDTO, mapped to a database column. The ZonePoint_DTO objects that you persist all have a `null` zoneDTO. So, what does JPA insert in the column? null. If you ant the database column not to be null, then the JPA property mapped to this column (zoneDTO) must not be null.

Comment: Why do you use an embedded ID class with a single field? Especially given that it's incorrectly implemented: no equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: @JBNizet Shouldn't it consider the parent while inserting the ZonePoint_DTO. I am sending ZonePoint_DTOs(Children) inside a ZoneDTO(Parent)? Do I need manually implement that?

Comment: A bidirectional association has an owner side and an inservse side. What matters to JPA is the owner side. And the owner side is the many side. Yes, you need to set the zoneDTO.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your inputs. I am adding proper setters in ZoneDTOs. Also, can you recommend any other method to save such parent entities in one or max two DB calls?